# jConfirm not waiting for user to response

Tags: javascript, callback

I have this javascript function. I need to change the confirm into jConfirm.

```
   var isValidSpecialityToSave =function(){
   var isValid = false;
   if(isEmpty("Specialtylist"))
     {
         jAlert("Speciality doesn't exist","Error");
      }
      else if(!isValidPrimary())
     {
        //Have to change this confirm to jConfirm
        if(confirm('Primary speciality already exists.Don't you want to overide it'))
                   {
                    isValid =true;
                   }
      }
      else{
              isValid =true;
          }
                return isValid;
     };
```

Now here is my code->

```
 else  if(!isValidPrimary())
 {
  jConfirm('Primary speciality already exists.Don't you want to overide it',"Warning",function(r)
   {
     if(r)
     {
     isValid=true;
     }
   });
 }
 else
     {
      isValid=false;
     }
      return isValid;
 };//End of function
```

Now the problem is that when the code gets into the else-if block, jConfirm appears on the screen, but the return statement(return isValid) is executed before the user can click Ok or Cancel. I can't even move the return statement into the jConfirm callback as then it will return isValid to the jConfirm callback function and "isValidSpecialityToSave" goes undefined.

Any way I can make this work? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Is this a stupid question?

Comment: is the isValid in the last else supposed to be set to true?

Comment: You'll need to rework the jconfirm to work insid eof !isValidPrimary instead of the main function because of the callback structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: 1) Escape your apostrophes. 2) jConfirm can't stop javascript processing like the built-in confirm function does. Your callback occurs after the user picks an option while the rest of the code keeps going. You need to rework your code so that whatever is receiving isValid is run within the jConfirm callback instead of waiting on a return from it.

Comment: The only other way would be to change back to the built-in confirm function which does stop javascript from continuing and will wait for the result.

Answer (score 0):

JConfirm or JAlert, your next step should be inside the callback function.  Eg. I have given below. I want to display a successful message after an Ajax post saving and the go to another page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please copy-paste the relevant part of the code in the answer? It's easier than a picture.